# Plone MailHost sends wrong Date header with Australian timezone

Tags: timezone, plone, zope

I've got a Plone instance that's being run for users in Sydney, so the TZ environment variable is set to `Australia/Sydney`. With this set, code that uses the `DateTime` module from Zope2 produces results that display the wrong timezone. For instance:

```
>>> import time
>>> import DateTime
>>> print time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %T %z") # 
Thu, 20 Sep 2012 02:38:08 +1000
>>> print DateTime.DateTime().rfc822()
Thu, 20 Sep 2012 02:38:08 -0400
```

This is rather problematic because `Products.MailHost` sets the `Date:` header on outgoing emails to the value `DateTime().rfc822()` (on line 466 of MailHost.py). Because the offset is wrong, the time in the Date header is now 12 hours into the future. SMTP servers receiving that email will often summarily reject it!

Other code in the same instance is quite happily behaving correctly with that TZ variable because it uses the `datetime` module in Python, which is all based on libc's `time.h` functions.

So, what do people do in order to get the Plone's MailHost to work in Australian time zones?

Comment: What does `print sys.modules['DateTime.DateTime']._findLocalTimeZoneName(0)` give you?

Comment: The timezone is calculated from `time.tzname` falling back to `time.timezone` or `time.altzone` based on the DST flag, so could you include those values too?

Comment: Running `TZ=Australia/Sydney bin/zopepy`, `import sys, DateTime; m = sys.modules['DateTime.DateTime']; print m._findLocalTimeZoneName(0), m._findLocalTimeZoneName(1)` prints `US/Eastern US/Eastern`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `TZ=Australia/Sydney` becomes `time.tzname == ('EST', 'EST')`:

```
$ TZ=Australia/Sydney bin/zopepy -c "import time; print time.tzname"
('EST', 'EST')
```

And the DateTime internal database translates that to `US/Eastern`. It is an unfortunate side-effect of Eastern Standard Time being the name for more than one timezone.

You'd need to specify a more explicit `TZ` variable specifying the offsets and the DST switch dates, with a new timezone name that won't be misinterpreted:

```
TZ="AEST-10AEDT-11,M10.1.0/02:00:00,M4.1.0/03:00:00"
```

The above value comes from the [still open bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/datetime/+bug/142148) and happens to be perfect for your purposes:

```
$ TZ="AEST-10AEDT-11,M10.1.0/02:00:00,M4.1.0/03:00:00" bin/zopepy
>>> import DateTime
>>> import sys
>>> m = sys.modules['DateTime.DateTime']
>>> m._findLocalTimeZoneName(0)
'GMT+10'
>>> m._findLocalTimeZoneName(1)
'GMT+11'
>>> import DateTime
>>> DateTime.DateTime()
DateTime('2012/09/21 00:12:0.765691 GMT+10')
>>> DateTime.DateTime().rfc822()
'Fri, 21 Sep 2012 00:12:04 +1000'
```

You can add the `TZ` environment variable to your Zope configuration by sepecifying it in the buildout:

```
[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
...
environment-vars =
    TZ AEST-10AEDT-11,M10.1.0/02:00:00,M4.1.0/03:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you! This'll work for now. When I get some time to throw at it, I'll write+submit a patch against DateTime. Do you know what the best way to contact Hanno would be, since he's listed as maintainer?

Comment: @RichardBarrell: Best use the https://mail.zope.org/mailman/listinfo/zope-dev mailinglist, Hanno reads the list.

Comment: Ach, this doesn't quite work either. DateTime().rfc822() now prints 'Thu, 20 Sep 2012 23:58:35 +0000' which is a different wrong %z value. For comparison, date -R prints 'Thu, 20 Sep 2012 28:58:35 +1000'.

Comment: Some context: https://bugs.launchpad.net/datetime/+bug/142148. It turns out I touched upon this 5 years ago too.

Comment: I've updated the answer ever so slightly with the exact TZ value from Dylan, and it works for me when printing the RFC822 timestamp. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Since DateTime now has a dependency on pytz, it should be possible to change its timezone logic to actually use the Olson database in pytz properly. When I get a chance, I'll write a patch for DateTime and bring it up on zope-dev.

Comment: Please do review the bug thread I linked, others have already attempted this and discovered that `dateutil.tz` would be required to deal with all the intricacies.